# How can I travel to Sweden with a Refugee Travel Document issued by the USA?

Tags: visas, usa, air-travel, sweden, refugees

I am an asylee in the United States. I am from Afghanistan and have an Afghanistan passport, but because I was granted asylum, I am not able to use my Afghanistan passport. I have an I-131 refugee travel document issued by USA. I want to travel to Sweden to visit family members.

How can I do it? Do I need a visa? Or it is visa-free for USA travel document holders? How long it is going to take to get a visa? What kind of documents do I have to provide?

I need to know details so I can plan appropriately. Also any source that provides more information would be great.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, unless you have a passport from a country that doesn't require visa to Sweden, a visa is required (you can check [here](https://www.copaair.com/en-ca/timatic/), for example). Follow the instructions [here](https://visa.vfsglobal.com/usa/en/swe/apply-visa).

Since you're an Afghani citizen, you'd need a visa to Sweden with your home country passport anyway. You do not have to use the Afghani passport if you have a US refugee travel document (in fact, you may not be allowed to, based on the comments), but you do need a visa. Only US *passport* holders can travel to Sweden visa-free for short visits. US *travel document (not a national passport)* holders need a visa.

Comment: This isn't really all that clear. It seems that the OP doesn't have a (usable) passport at all. He's got one from Afghanistan, but it seems that asylum status has, essentially, voided the Afghan passport.

Comment: My answer was written before the information about Afghanistan was edited in. I'll update it.

Comment: Ah, my bad. I didn't look at timestamps. Sorry.

Comment: "Only US passport holders can travel to Sweden visa-free for short visits." This sentence is misleading, since people with passports from many other countries can also travel to Sweden visa-free.

Comment: @CrisLuengo I emphasized *passport* as opposed to *travel document*.

Comment: OP **cannot** use their Afghanistan passport. The way US asylum law works, that would cause OP to lose their asylee status in the United States. Similarly, they must apply for a Swedish visa _on their US travel document_, not on their Afghanistan passport.

Comment: @A.R. wasn't aware of that. Do you have references? Anyway, added to the answer, thanks

Comment: @A.R. it's not just US asylum law; it's in the refugee convention.  The US is actually rather more lax on this question that it has to be; see for example https://www.asylumist.com/2022/05/25/traveling-with-your-passport-when-you-have-asylum/ -- they mostly don't like it if you have lied in your initial claim.  Once you have a green card, if the situation at home has genuinely changed, you don't jeopardize your status by using your national passport.

Comment: From the above link: *"In general, the risk to your status caused by using your passport is probably minimal, though it is not zero"*. It doesn't look like there's an actual blanket prohibition on using the home passport for travel, but circumstances matter.

Answer (score 0):

I want to clarify the issue:

1. You will travel on your U.S. Refugee Travel document
2. You will need a visa for traveling to Sweden on the document.

- But do check with the Swedish Embassy as these rules may change. Some countries allow visa-free entry, not Sweden as far as I know.